# How to write multiple For Each statement in JSTL, with begin, end and var attributes?

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

How to use multiple JSTL for-each loop having end, var and begin attributes in JSP?

I am running into an issue where i have two for-each statements. The content inside first statement is getting displayed; but for second for each loop it is not displaying anything.

```
<c:forEach end="${economy.flagBank}" var="loopIndex" begin="1">
 1
</c:forEach>
<c:forEach end="${economy.flagTank}" var="loopIndex" begin="1">
  2
</c:forEach>
 //   Both flagBank and flagTank have 1.

 Output: 1
```

Is there any error in above statements? I need to write around 10 for-each in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible explanation is, that ${economy.flagTank} is not 1 as you wrote.

```
                <c:forEach end="1" var="loopIndex" begin="1">
                    1
                </c:forEach>
                <c:forEach end="1" var="loopIndex" begin="1">
                    2
                </c:forEach>
```

produces an output of 1 2, so you have to have something like ${economy.flagTank} < 1